# Science fiction story about a giant robot performing simple math problems

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

I remember reading it about a decade ago in school, I seem to recall the giant robot maybe being angry that he couldn't make 2 numbers add up to each other.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a shot story "Trurl's Machine" from Stanislaw Lem's *Cyberiad*.

Giant computer insists that two plus two is seven and things soon become violent.

> Once upon a time Trurl the constructor built an eight-story thinking machine. [...]
>
> Extremely pleased with himself, he whistled an air and, as is always done on such occasions, asked it the ritual question of how much is two plus two.
>
> The machine stirred. Its tubes began to glow, its coils warmed up [...]
>
> "SEVEN!" snapped the machine. Trurl sighed and put his coveralls back on, rolled up his sleeves, opened the bottom trapdoor and crawled in.
>
> [... They argue about this for some time, and the machine flies into a rage ...]
>
> The machine was gathering momentum, clearly bent on running them down, so they fled just as fast as they could, the fearful rhythm of crunching steps in their ears.